# Fetching and showing DB values with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, jstl

I'm making a web application where you need to register and login.
Very basic, I know but I'm learning it.

Now I want to show a list of checkboxes in a JSP page.
I have something like this:

```
 <% KokenHelper kh= new KokenHelper(); %>
      <c:forEach var="wat" items="${kh.getAllKoken()}" >
           <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="wat" value="${wat}"> ${wat}
                </label>
           </div>
      </c:forEach>
```

I made a KokenHelper class that gets a List object, that is what I need to show.

Any tips are welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, dont use `Java` code in a `jsp` page

```
<% KokenHelper kh= new KokenHelper(); %>
```

`JSTL` **IT'S DEPRECATED AND HIGHLY DISCOURAGED**:

---

**Second**: `KokenHelper` class must have the list of Koken as private attribute and it's publics getters and setters:

```
class KokenHelper {
    private List<Koken> kokenList;

    // getter and setter!!!
}
```

---

**Third**, depending how you pass the information from java to view you can get the `kokenList` via:

```
${applicationScope.kokenHelper.kokenList}
```

using a form:

```
<form:form role="form" method="post" commandName="kokenHelper" action="../formAction" id="formId">
    <c:forEach var="wat" items="${kokenHelper.kokenList}" >
</form:form>
```

But to be more concrete I should have more info...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that I might not use java in a jsp page but I don't know how I'm supposed to do it without. The second step like mine. The problem is in the Third step: I don't know how to pass the data to the jsp...

Comment: Wat more info do you need? I'll post it

Comment: there is plenty of ways, first one `${applicationScope.kokenHelper.kokenList}` should work in all cases... also [check this](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jsp%20tutorial%20java)